# PowerBI - lookup - is a value that's in column 1 in column 2?

Tags: powerbi, calculated-columns

This is something that I can do in my sleep with Excel but I am struggling with this basic thing in PowerBI.  I have a column in my Items table called ID and another column in the same table called ParentID.

What I am looking to do in PowerBI is create the CalcColumn - Looking up to see if an ID is in the Parent ID column and bringing back a response

I've tried several different variations of a calculated column using the lookup value function but I either bring back the parent id for a value (which I already have), I bring back random id numbers (that are neither the id nor the parent) or it tells me that I've got multiple values.

| ID | ParentID | CalcColum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | Parent |
| 2 | 1 | Not found |
| 3 |  | Parent |
| 4 | 1 | Parent |
| 5 | 3 | Not found |
| 6 | 4 | Parent |
| 7 | 6 | Not found |
| 8 |  | Not found |

How would I resolve this?

Comment: I think this will help you: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Check-if-a-value-exist-in-another-column/td-p/1800995 -- It is about two different tables but I believe you can change that, without any problem, to the same table but two different columns. Instead of 'yes' and 'no' you should ofcourse use 'Parent' and 'Not found'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fairly straightforward in DAX too.

Try this expression as a calculated column:

```
IF ( Table1[ID] IN VALUES ( Table1[ParentID] ), "Parent", "Not found" )
```